# What are these sets of Pythagorean triples called?

Tags: terminology

There are sets of Pythagorean triples 
$$ \{ a, b, c\} $$
where any pair of numbers is relative prime, like {3, 4, 5} and {5, 12, 13}, and there are sets with common factors
$$ \{ n \cdot a, n \cdot b, n \cdot c \} $$
like the obvious {6, 8, 10} or {30, 40, 50}. What are both sets called?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples

Comment: "Primitive Pythagorean triples" and "Non-primitive Pythagorean triples".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer says in a comment, a pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ where $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ is usually called a *primitive* pythagorean triple.  The antonym is "non-primitive".

Answer (score 0):

The ones who have not common factors are called primitive pythagorean triplets, the ones who have non-primitive pythagorean triplets.

BYE!